# Which file types should I gzip before sending to client?

Tags: node.js, webserver

I don't want to gzip everything I send to the client by default, so I am whitelisting the content types I want to gzip:

```
var contentTypesToGzip = [
    'text/html',
    'application/x-javascript',
    'text/css',
    'application/javascript',
    'text/javascript',
    'text/plain',
    'text/xml',
    'application/json',
    'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
    'application/x-font-opentype',
    'application/x-font-truetype',
    'application/x-font-ttf',
    'application/xml',
    'font/eot',
    'font/opentype',
    'font/otf',
    'image/svg+xml',
    'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
];
```

Am I missing anything? Do you have any comments as far as best practices around gzipping? Never gzip images, video, and audio, right?